# Which currency for play money?

Tags: money, exchange

I'm running a (one off) game for some friends (in the UK), in which notes will be required.  I think it's probably cheaper to do currency exchange for some actual bank notes, then change it back again afterwards; rather than buy toy money.

I have specific needs (60*1, 60*5, 24*10, 6*50) in notes.

Two questions really:

1. Would a currency exchange be likely to fulfill my request for exact note amounts like that?
2. What is the cheapest available currency that would have notes in those denominations.  While I trust my friends, I don't really want to play with 900 USD worth of cash.

Comment: Does any country aside from the US still have 1-unit notes?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about travel in any way.

Comment: Why not just buy a Monopoly set in a charity shop?

Comment: I agree that it's probably unlikely that any country whose unit of currency is worth significantly less than 1 USD would print 1-unit notes. So you are presumably talking about several hundred USD of value. When you exchange your pounds to this other currency and then back, you'll lose the amount of the spread, plus any commission (twice). That's probably at least a few percent. So this scheme will likely cost you at least 20 USD or so - you can buy a lot of play money at your local toy shop for that price.

Comment: Also, if you choose an obscure currency with a low value per unit, your local bank or currency exchange may only stock high-denomination notes.

Comment: Even for common currencies, currency exchanges almost never have small denomination notes in stock.

Comment: You might try this on http://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/ - it's a place for asking off-the-wall questions and solving things unusually. I think using real currency to sub for play money might qualify.

Comment: Saudi riyal will do that for you (notes of 1, 5, 10, 20, 50, 100, 200, 500 are available), it will be around $250 USD if exchanged.

Comment: It is not hard to make play money yourself, for much less than buying play money.

Answer (score 5):

I'd forget about the selling back part, and **just buy worthless notes off eBay**!

[image]
(courtesy Banknote World)

For example, [this seller](http://www.ebay.com.au/usr/banknoteworldcom?_trksid=p2047675.l2559)  sells unused notes in bulk from all sorts of obscure countries, including [these lovely packs of Mongolian 1, 5, 10 and 50 tugrik notes](http://www.ebay.com.au/sch/m.html?_odkw=mongolia&_ssn=banknoteworldcom&_armrs=1&_osacat=11116&_from=R40&_trksid=p2046732.m570.l1313.TR5.TRC0.A0.H0.Xmongolia%20x%20100.TRS0&_nkw=mongolia%20x%20100&_sacat=11116), with each pack of 100 notes selling for around 6 GBP (plus shipping).  Or maybe you'd like some [Kyrgyzstani tyiyn](http://www.ebay.com.au/itm/Kyrgyzstan-10-Tyiyn-X-100-Pieces-PCS-1993-P-2-UNC-Bundle-Pack-/271788722211?pt=LH_DefaultDomain_0&hash=item3f47dec823)?  This means you could get beautiful mint notes for well under 10 pence a pop.

And in case you were thinking about selling them back anyway, at time of writing 1 tugrik is worth around 0.0005 USD.

Comment: Zimbabwe currency would go a long way in this context..

Comment: @RussellMcMahon Yes, if they're OK with using 1 trillion dollar notes instead...

Comment: You can get a pack of play money that would satisfy the requirements for about $6.